# C++ and initialize const variable

Tags: c++

I want to create class Test with const int variable with name "a". After that I need create constructor where variable "a" get value =10. I Create class test and in test.h I create `const int a;` in class Test.h and in test.cpp I have something like that:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"


Test::Test(void)
{
    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    size = 20;
    tekst[size];
    }

Test::~Test(void)
{
}
```

and this is test.h:

```
#pragma once
class Test
{

    const int a;  



public:
    Test(void);
    ~Test(void);
    int b;
    char *tekst;
    int size;
    static double d;
    int y;
};
```

but I get error:

```
Error   1   error C2758: 'Test::a' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list    c:\users\bożydar\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\test.cpp 6
Error   2   error C2166: l-value specifies const object c:\users\bożydar\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\test.cpp 7
```

Comment: I'm sure searching *constructor base/member initializer list* on Google will pull up some good results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error says it all, `a must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list`

```
Test::Test(void) : a(10) // Initializer list
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you what to do

```
Test::Test(void) : a(10) // an initializer list
{
    b = 20;
    size = 20;
    tekst[size];
}
```

BTW i think you'll find that the code

```
tekst[size];
```

does not do what you expect it to. Probably you mean

```
tekst = new char[size];
```

Comment: The initializer list should be used for *everything*, not just for those cases where you absolutely must... And the local declaration of `tekst` is completely off.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in an initialization list:

```
Test::Test(void) : a(10) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` is const, so you cannot assign to it. You must, however, initialize it.

Do:

```
Test::Test(void)
:a(10)
{
    ...
}
```

BTW, the `tekst[size]` doesn't do what you think, probably. It does nothing!

Comment: It *might* do nothing. It *might* do something. Technically, its behavior is undefined.